# EF core not creating tables on migrate method

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Hey I just started using EF core and everything works fine. I call the the `context.Database.Migrate()` method and it creates a database. But even though my context object has a `DBSet<T>`, it doesn't create any tables except for the migration history.

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: Have you called `Add-Migration`?

Comment: Yes I did. But I still want by db to be initiated by code itself..

Comment: `Add-Migration` generates code, `context.Database.Migrate()` migrates it using that code.

Comment: Okay. But it still wont work. In both cases, it just creates database. not tables

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`context.Database.Migrate()` in itself does not *generate migrations*. Instead, it processes your created migrations.

For each database change, you should call `Add-Migration {sensibleName}`.

Your startup class would continue to call `context.Database.Migrate()` which will check your database and process any outstanding migrations.

For example once you have created your database, a general rule is to call `Add-Migration Initial`. Calling `context.Database.Migrate()` once will check your database exists, create it if not, check if `Initial` migration is applied, and apply it if not.

If you then call `Add-Migration SmallChange`, the same will happen on next startup, similar to the following:

1. Does database exist? Yes
2. Has migration Initial been applied? Yes
3. Has migration SmallChange been applied? No
4. Apply Migration SmallChange

Your first migration should look a little something like this:

```
public partial class Initial : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "HelloWorld",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
                MyString = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
            });
    }
}
```

If your migration doesn't look like that, it may be that your `DbContext` isn't correctly configured. If your tables still aren't being applied, try running the database update from your Package Manager Console and see what exactly is happening with `Update-Database -Verbose`

Comment: Understood. But that's my point. I created initial migration. But my `Up()` and `Down()` methods are empty and no table is generated.

Comment: Alright - In SQL Server Management Studio (or whichever tool you're using), drop your database thats been created. Clear out your Migrations folder, and then try `Add-Migration Initial` again.

Comment: So now it worked. What if I add DBSet<T> later in stage. will I have to do the above steps(the command line call to Update-Database) again. Is there a way to do that in C#?

Comment: No, the `context.Database.Migrate()` method in your code is synonymous to `Update-Database`  Now that you have an initial migration in place, any changes to your `DbContext` (or models within) will create a differencing migration. I'd suggest you give it a try now, change a model and call `Add-Migration` to see what happens. TLDR `Add-Migration` is always required, your `c.Db.Migrate()` call will apply them!

Comment: Is there something like automatic migrations in EF core?

Comment: Entity Framework Core does not have Automatic Migrations, no. They tend to only be useful in development scenarios anyway, so I wouldn't rely on them.

Comment: This worked for me instead of applying in the context itself. I used to to do in the Context but then i created another project which did not let me migrate on it.

Comment: I had my migration working very fine till I changed the connection string. I wanted to create same model in prod database. The context.Database.Migrate() didnt work. It only did create [__EFMigrationsHistory] table but no records in it.

Answer (score 12):

So I fought with this for a long time and I couldn't figure it out.  My migrations are in the application project while my DbContext was in another.

When creating the options for the context you want to apply the migrations to you need to specify the MigrationAssembly.

```
serviceCollection.AddDbContext<YourContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(_configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionString"), b => b.MigrationsAssembly("Your.Assembly")));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Nice answer.

Comment: After a whole day of fighting this, this ended up being the answer for me!

Comment: This is what I was missing. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 5):

I did the follow and works:

1. Erase Migrations Folder in my APP project.
2. Standing on DataAccess project, where I got persistency declared (EF, Dbcontext, etc)
   2.1 Add-Migration Initial . 
   2.2 Update DataBase from console.

Answer (score 4):

I will supplement the answer that is marked as correct. In my case, the migration did not work, although everything was as in the answer above. The EF tools update helped me: `dotnet tool update --global dotnet-ef`

Comment: FYI that supplements to existing answers should be added as comments rather than as new answers.

Comment: I know, but I don't have enough reputation

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a database, nor any migrations created (no `Migrations` folder in your project), then calling `Migrate` will create the database without any tables.

If you want the tables to be created as well, one option is to call `EnsureCreated` instead of `Migrate`:

```
context.Database.EnsureCreated()
```

This will create the database *and* the tables. **However, the generated database won't be updatable later using migrations. So this should only be used in limited cases, such as when testing or prototyping.**

Comment: `EnsureCreated` will create the tables in your current model, but it won't create a fake migration history. This is poor advice as it will leave your database in a state where future migrations will break.